# How to capture a index of div and add selected attribute to an option of the same index in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have created a set of `div` elements which have the same class and a `select` element. When I click on particular `div` item it should capture that index and add the selected attribute to same index of `option`. I tried something like the below but the `selected` attribute is added to all `option` elements.

```
.container, .selectItem {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="group">
        <a class="change">ABC</a>
    </div>
    <div class="group">
        <a class="change">PQR</a>
    </div>
    <div class="group">
        <a class="change">XYZ</a>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <select class="selectItem">
        <option>ABC</option>
        <option>PQR</option>
        <option>XYZ</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a.change').click(function(){
        var changeIndex = $(this).closest('.group').index('.group');
        console.log(changeIndex);
        $('.selectItem').find('option').attr("selected", "selected");
    });
})
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sandenay/8unsmgvo/

Comment: Is this what you are trying to do?

Comment: Yes Sandeep.

Thanks for help.

I found another solution for this:

http://jsfiddle.net/chandru02010/d28xhstw/

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$('a.change').click(function(){
    var idx = $(this).parents('.group').index();
    $('.selectItem option').eq(idx).attr("selected", "selected");
});
```

See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sn0j5L05/)

Answer (score 1):

I did something like this:

Only changes

```
....
var index = $(this).closest(".group").index();

//console.log(text);
$('.selectItem').find('option').eq(index).attr("selected","selected");
....
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){


$('a.change').click(function(){
    
    var index = $(this).closest(".group").index();
    
    //console.log(text);
    $('.selectItem').find('option').eq(index).attr("selected","selected");


});

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
<div class="group">
  <a class="change">ABC</a>
</div>
<div class="group">
  <a class="change">PQR</a>
</div>
<div class="group">
  <a class="change">XYZ</a>
</div>
</div>

<div>
<select class="selectItem">
        <option>ABC</option>
        <option>PQR</option>
        <option>XYZ</option>
</select>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks to all for answering my question.
:)

Answer (score 0):

Here is jquery grep solution if values in divs are exactly the same in the combo box:

```
    $('a.change').click(function(){
       var $currentItem=$(this);
       var $optionToSelect=$($.grep($('.selectItem option'),function(item,index){
         return $(item).text().toLowerCase()===$currentItem.text().toLowerCase()
    })).attr('selected','selected');
    });
```